# Accessing the properties window of wireless network connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Can anyone tell me what to do get to the "properties" pop up window for my wireless networks?
When I right-click on a wireless network sometimes it ought to show the options "connect", "diagnose" and "properties", but it just says "connect" and I really need to get to the properties to change the connection key in order to connect to it. What do I do?

Comment: Does looking up the interface in device manager help?

Comment: I found the solution guys, Thanks a lot. I simply went to Network and Sharing Center->Manage Wireless Networks, then I clicked on "Add" and manually entered the exact name of my network, and it worked! from there I could edit the properties. I really should come here more often.

Comment: @Peter: Please post that as an answer if you can and then accept it as the solution. That would be much appreciated.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg; done, had to wait for 7 hours, apparently I have to wait again for 2days to accept my own answer. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I simply went to *Network and Sharing Center » Manage Wireless Networks*, then I clicked on "Add" and manually entered the exact name of my network, and it worked!

From there I could edit the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can always go to Network and Sharing Center and hit Manage Wireless Networks. From there, you can right-click on the network to change properties.

Comment: tried that, my network is not listed there, what's "all else"?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing: It was me trying to say "there may be other ways, but this should certainly work". Is there a "New Connection" button? Try clicking that.

Comment: I understood you, what I meant to ask was 'What are the other ways?' I have a wireless router that I need to connect to and I need to change the connection key

Comment: You need to forget the network in that case and re-connect to the AP